# HTML formatting in Android's new data binding library

Tags: android, data-binding

Using the new [data binding library](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) of Android, can I use HTML formatting for `TextView` through XML only or do I have to use `Html.fromHtml` programmatically?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You must import Html and then call the fromHtml method :

```
<data>
    <import type="android.text.Html"/>
</data>
…
<TextView
    android:text="@{Html.fromHtml(@string/my_html)}"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: This is right answer, except when you have dynamic data which can be null on specific time this will lead to NPE From Binding class (thrown by fromHtml itself).
So @Fragment and remy 's answer is perfect in any case.

Answer (score 3):

In case if you want to use string with html tags and combine it with string parameters, it could be done in a such way:

In layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{activity.formattedString}" />
```

In your activity (for ex):

```
public CharSequence getFormattedString() {
    if(selectedItem == null) return null;
    String str = String.format(Html.toHtml(SpannedString.valueOf(this.getResources().getText(R.string.your_tagged_string))), parameter);
    return Html.fromHtml(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Transforms should not be done in the view. The viewmodel is here to do transform operations between your raw model and your view.

So I would rather do it like that :

```
<data>
  <variable
  name="viewModel"
  type="yourpackage.YourViewModel"/>
</data>
…
<TextView
   android:text="@{viewModel.htmlText}"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In your viewmodel :

```
private Model model; // your model

public Spanned getHtmlText(){
    return Html.fromHtml(model.htmlText);
}
```

Comment: I think this solution violates the principle of independence of api elements within the view model, because Spanned and Html are elements from Android API, then when you are gonna be testing this, you'll need to use an emulator or an actual device

Answer (score 0):

I have a more elegant, efficient and reusable answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60119785/6248208) covering this particular scenario

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load data from server/viewmodel then do this.
Pass **null** in empty or else case

```
<import type="android.text.Html"/>
<variable
        name="vm"
        type="com.example.ProductVM" />

<TextView
  ..
  android:text="@{!TextUtils.isEmpty(vm.htmlText) ? Html.fromHtml(vm.htmlText) : null}"
  />
```