# Html.fromHtml in DataBinding - Android

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using from `dataBinding` in my project,when I have bellow `xml` it good work :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDateCreate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{String.format(@string/DateCreate,others.created)}" />
```

But when I change to bellow get me crash:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDateCreate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{Html.fromHtml(String.format(@string/DateCreate,others.created))}" />
```

Here in my `string.xml` :

```
<resources>
<string name="DateCreate">open : <![CDATA[<b><font color=#FF0000>%s</b>]]></string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Think you need to import html first in the xml

```
<data>
    <import type="android.text.Html"/>
</data>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDateCreate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{Html.fromHtml(String.format(@string/DateCreate,others.created))}" />
```

Comment: i am trying to implement your solution but the text that i am getting is from an API call, so at the first init of the screen the string is null and the app crashes, how can i implement it to work around that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72457240/9427138 -> check this out

Answer (score 7):

I think that the view should not have any logic/transformation to display the data. What I'd recommend to do is creating a BindingAdapter for this:

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:htmlText"})
public static void setHtmlTextValue(TextView textView, String htmlText) {
    if (htmlText == null)
        return;

    Spanned result;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        result = Html.fromHtml(htmlText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        result = Html.fromHtml(htmlText);
    }
    textView.setText(result);
}
```

Then within the layout call it as usual:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/bid_footer"
                style="@style/MyApp.TextView.Footer"
                android:htmlText="@{viewModel.bidFooter} />
```

Where *viewModel.bidFooter* has the logic to get the String/Spanned/Chars with the text, taking into consideration not having any direct dependence to context, activity, etc

Comment: What if you want to use a string resource ID directly? I.e. no viewmodel.

Comment: It would be something like having all your logic within your activity/fragment or an util/ktx class ... then after you have the data value, define a data-binding variable within the layout and set the value there from the activity/fragment

Answer (score 1):

The line below is deprecated in Android N (API level 24).

```
Html.fromHtml(content)
```

Now you're supposed to provide two params (content and flag) like below:

```
Html.fromHtml(content, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

So I'll suggest you use **@BindingAdapter** like below:

```
object BindingUtils {

@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("loadHtml")
fun loadHtml(textView: TextView, content: String?){
    if (!content.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        textView.text = if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Html.fromHtml(content, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
        } else {
            Html.fromHtml(content)
        }
    }
}
```

}

and in your XML file:

```
 <data>
    <import type="com.example.utils.BindingUtils"/>
</data>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:loadHtml="@{String.format(@string/DateCreate,others.created))}"/>
```

Comment: Helpful answer!  A few things to note: 1) HtmlCompat.fromHtml(content, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY) can be used to avoid the need for checking the SDK version.  2) For string.xml resources, Html tags or their opening bracket '<' need to be escaped to prevent the Android system from automatically removing them. 3) The last sentence above contains an extra closing parenthesis ')'.